# An integral in the heat kernel expression for index calculation

Tags: integration

a quick question. I was reading this [paper](https://journals.aps.org/prd/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevD.16.1052), on the last page, the authors wrote
$$
\lim_{\mu^2\rightarrow\infty} \text{Tr} \int_0^\infty dT\ e^{-T} \Big(e^{-(T/\mu^2)LL^\dagger}-e^{-(T/\mu^2)L^\dagger L}\Big) = \lim_{t\rightarrow0}\text{Tr} \Big(e^{-tLL^\dagger}-e^{-tL^\dagger L}\Big).
$$
Anyone has any ideas how to show this equality? I do believe the formula is correct because something very similar showed up in Nakahara's topology book, in equation (12.110) in the second edition I own, where he said the index of a two-term complex can be written as $\text{Tr}\big(\frac{s}{\Delta_E+s}-\frac{s}{\Delta_F+s}\big) $ for arbitrary $s$. but he did not include a derivation either. Thanks in advance!